# Can't disable secure boot on 16.04 running on virtual machine

Tags: nvidia, openstack, gpu-driver

04 instance running on a cloud (OpenStack) and it can't load the NVIDIA drivers. I've tried to disable secure boot with

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

but I get an error

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

anyhow, the NVIDIA drivers still won't load.